# Javascript Capabilities: Self-governing speed?

Tags: javascript, architecture

#### Background

I can't quite figure out how to ask this question the right way, but here is my best shot.

Is there a way to give Javascript the ability to govern its own speed? It would basically be choosing its frame rate dynamically. It would never fire more than the browser could handle, ideally a little less. Animations would be calculated on the current time, and increment dynamically based on that current time.

#### Question

- Is there a better way to ask this question? Any vernacular I should have used?
- Is this question to broad? Are there multiple ways to solve this problem?
- If this question isn't too broad, what is(are) the solution(s) if any?

Comment: Do you want to monitor CPU usage from JavaScript?

Comment: That's a good question. Not really, but If that's the only way, then so be it. I'm hoping for a built-in / third party solution. Something simple. I'm wondering if it is out there or if I'll need to build my own.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which is provided by the browser (it's not part of JavaScript, the language)

Comment: I think you might be right. What would happen if a utilized `requestAnimationFrame` on a function, but that function ran for two frames? Would the browser adjust the framerate automatically?

Comment: @jacob no it would skip one render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to give Javascript the ability to govern its own speed?

No. Javascript will run as fast as possible and when the browser wants to run it, so you cannot change the way "how fast it runs". If JS code gets executed, the browser gets blocked wich means that:

```
  while(true) {
    document.body.textContent = new Date();
  }
```

will crash the browser instead of showing the current time.

> It would basically be choosing its frame rate dynamically.

Thats a different thing. The browser paints whatever you hand to him (e.g. a canvas), and it rerenders that at roughly 60fps. Inside JS you could shedule a small task, that runs every few milliseconds and updates the canvas, then the browser will render that for you. E.g.:

```
 setInterval(function update() {
   document.body.textContent = new Date();
 }, 100);
```

> It would never fire more than the browser could handle, ideally a little less. Animations would be calculated on the current time, and increment dynamically based on that current time.

Thats where `requestAnimationFrame` comes in. Thats a browser API which will execute the passed callback before the next rerender, so roughly at 60fps, you have to set it recursively:

```
 (function update() {
    document.body.textContent = new Date();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
 })();
```

That way the next update will only happen after the current finished, the browser will only rerender after the update function ender, so if your function takes very long to calculate the update, it will lag / freeze.

Comment: "Inside JS you could schedule a small task, that runs every few milliseconds and updates the canvas, then the browser will render that for you." - Just making sure I get this right, you're saying I calculate my animations outside the DOM, and update them using the requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: @jacob basically yes, you could also directly work with the DOM, the updates will then get reflected to the rendered page.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the `requestAnimationFrame` function is there to ensure I don't fire any redundant code?

Comment: @jacob basically its nearly the same as `setTimeout`